# How to show input form not changing url like Twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'd like to show an input form not changing url like Twitter.
I have been developing by rails and used bootstrap as css framework.
I am able to show the form by using action as following code. However, I'd like to make it not changing screen.

I am new to web front end development, thus I don't know very much about JavaScript.
Sorry to ask an easy question. Thank you.

```
#app/controllers/questions_controller
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = User.new(user_params)
    @question.save!
  end

  def show
    # @questions_range = Question.period(3.day.ago, Time.now)
    # @questions = @questions_range.order("score DESC")
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  private 

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :body) 
end

#app/views/questions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @question, :url => questions_path do |f| %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Question</h1>
  </div>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <td><%= f.text_field :body %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: pls show what you have tried so far. and include relevant code in question

Comment: Check out this guide. It works well: http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html

Comment: Dear Pekka
I've added controller and view. plz check it.

Comment: Dear Dustin
Thank you! I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accepted the answer of DustinFisher.
http://goo.gl/S8L6ZW